# Elasticsearch: how to query a long field for exact match

Tags: elasticsearch

My document has the following mapping property:

```
"sid" : {"type" : "long", "store": "yes", "index": "no"},
```

This property has only one value for each record. I would like to query this property. I tried the following queries:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : {
             "sid" : 10
        }
    }
}

{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
             "sid" : 10
        }
    }
}
```

However, I got no results. I do have a document with sid being euqal to 10. Anything I did is wrong? I would like to query this property for exact match.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html):

> `index`: Set to `analyzed` for the field to be indexed and searchable after being
>   broken down into token using an analyzer. `not_analyzed` means that its
>   still searchable, but does not go through any analysis process or
>   broken down into tokens. `no` means that it won’t be searchable at all
>   (as an individual field; it may still be included in `_all`). Setting to
>   `no` disables `include_in_all`. Defaults to `analyzed`.

So, by setting `index` to `no` you cannot search by that field individually. So, you either need to remove `no` from `index` and choose something else or you can use `"include_in_all":"yes"` and use a different type of query:

```
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": 10
    }
  }
```